# Groups not visible despite correct ACL after going from 5.18 to 5.35

Tags: groups, permissions, acl

Users with visibility to a group of contacts no longer see that group as selectable in search.

At first I suspected that migration failed in some way, but after creating a whole new group, group permissions etc – the whole chain of permissions – it's still not working, making me suspect a bug. Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: Yes, this is my greatest problem in Civi.